# App crash when rerender: Exception thrown while executing UI block: * -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps, react-native-map-clustering

I'm trying to build a map with clustering. At first, render everything works fine, but as soon as a user tries to move map or zoom, I'm recalculating markers/clusters postions, and app breaks on iOS with error: Exception thrown while executing UI block: * -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil

or

when i filter the markers or change in marker array data its same error throw

```js
 <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        shouldRasterizeIOS
        mapType="standard"
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION}
        animationEnabled
        
      >
        {data &&
          data?.map(item => (
            <CustomMarker
              item={item}
              key={item?.id}
              setSelectedMarkerId={(row: any) => {
                mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion(
                  {
                    latitude: Number(row?.lat),
                    longitude: Number(row?.long),
                    latitudeDelta: 0.06,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.06,
                  },
                  1000,
                );
              }}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: Number(item?.lat),
                longitude: Number(item?.long),
              }}
            />
          ))}
      </MapView>
```

[Error of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrokQ.png)

Dependencies:-
[react-native-map-clustering](https://github.com/venits/react-native-map-clustering)   react-native-maps